# react-native-nfc-manager error causing`[Error: You can only issue one request at a time] `

Tags: javascript, react-native, tags, nfc, react-native-nfc-manager

**i m using react native nfc manager and reading a tag while reading a tag an error occurs frequently after one execution
here is my code: **

```
async function readData() {
console.log('readData>>>>>>');
            try {
          console.log('try in read>>>>');
            // register for the NFC tag with NDEF in it
            await NfcManager.requestTechnology(NfcTech.Ndef, {
                alertMessage: 'Hold your phone close to the NFC tag.',
            });
            // the resolved tag object will contain `ndefMessage` property
            const tag = await NfcManager.getTag();
            console.log('Tag found read', tag);
            const payload = tag?.ndefMessage[0].payload;
            //remove the language code from payload
            const subPayload = payload?.slice(3, payload.length);
            const decoded = Ndef.util.bytesToString(subPayload);
            console.log('done', decoded);
            const result = decoded.split('|');
            if (result.length === 2)
            Actions.asset({
                title: `Asset Details`,
                assetId: result[0],
                assetTypeId: result[1],
                screenNameValue: `Asset Details`,
              });
            NfcManager.cancelTechnologyRequest();
        } catch (ex) {
          NfcManager.cancelTechnologyRequest();
          console.warn('Oops in Read!', ex);
        } finally {
          NfcManager.cancelTechnologyRequest();
        }
     }
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: One reason: error code "42" - the error is in front of the screen. For a better help kindly provide more information like the error stack. Please edit your question and append the missing data, thanks.